# TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title doesn't color the text

Tags: xml, colors, android-actionbar

I'm developing an Android app, and I want to color the text on the actionbar, so I have the following code:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>

</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>

</style>
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.Title" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

And I want to make the color of the text on the actionbar white, however I do manage to color the actionbar but not the text!

Answer (score 0):

you could try to just put a  around your text specifically

Yourtext

That's all I can think of it's more css added.

Comment: That was deprecated since API 2 or something,

Comment: No I meant like right before your text type <font size="5px" color="white"> sdjfkajsdjf </font>

Comment: I actually set the title in the Java code with the setTitle() method.